# agora unity screenshare sound

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, agora.io

can it make sound from a screen-share function on the Unity desktop?
(sound from the video that shared)
Unity Desktop
I tried to make a screen-share function with sounds by setting below. However, it still didn't work at all. Are there any other options to be able to produce sound with a screen-share function?
option
options.publishScreenCaptureAudio.SetValue(true);
options.publishScreenCaptureVideo.SetValue(true);
sample code is designed to be mobile only.

Comment: RtcEngine.EnableLoopbackRecording(true);
Solved.